# SingleLinkedListWorkSheetQ2Q3.java:14: error: incompatible types: ListNode<Integer> cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: java

I'm trying to construct a single linked list. The single linked list has a method, addLast, that adds a node to the tail of the linked list. I created a *LList2 *class to store the first and last node of the list.

The error occurs when I try to use the addLast method in the driver class. Below is my code. Any suggestions would be helpful!

`

```
// Part One Question 2,3

public class SingleLinkedListWorkSheetQ2Q3{
   public static void main (String[] args){
      ListNode<Integer> rear = new ListNode<>(0, null);
      ListNode<Integer> list = new ListNode<>(1, rear);
      list = new ListNode<>(2, list);
      list = new ListNode<>(3, list);
      
      LList2 <Integer> temp = new LList2 <> (list, rear);
      
      temp.printWhile();
      
      temp.addLast(new ListNode<Integer> (-2, null));
   }
}

class ListNode <E> {
   private E val;
   private ListNode <E> next;
   
   public ListNode(E val, ListNode <E> next){
      this.val = val;
      this.next = next;
   }
   
   public E getVal(){
      return val;
   }
   
   public ListNode <E> getNext(){
      return next;
   }
   
   public void updateNext(ListNode <E> node){
      next = node;
   }
}



class LList2 <E> {
   private ListNode <E> front;
   private ListNode <E> rear;
   
   public LList2(ListNode <E> front, ListNode <E> rear){
      this.front = front;
      this.rear = rear;
   }
   
   public void printWhile(){
      System.out.print("[");
      while(front != null){
         System.out.print(front.getVal() + ", ");
         front = front.getNext();
      }
      System.out.print("]");
   }
   
   public void printFor(){
      System.out.print("[");
      for(ListNode <E> temp = front; temp != null; temp = temp.getNext()){
         System.out.print(temp.getVal() + ", ");
      }
      System.out.print("]");
   }
   
   // obj represents value
   public void addFirst(E obj){
      front = new ListNode<E>(obj, front);
      if(front.getNext() == null){
         rear = front;
      }
   }
   
   public void addLast(E obj){
      if(rear != null)
         rear.updateNext(new ListNode<E>(obj, null));
      else{
         rear = new ListNode<E>(obj, null);
         front = rear;
         
      }
      
   }
   
   

}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Because you were using the [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) Java compiler will [erase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) all `E` to the `Integer` type, so you can't set the `ListNode<Integer>`

the code will be this:

```java
package com.github.lemon.office;

import joptsimple.internal.Strings;

public class SingleLinkedListWorkSheetQ2Q3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode<Integer> rear = new ListNode<>(0, null);
        ListNode<Integer> list = new ListNode<>(1, rear);
        list = new ListNode<>(2, list);
        list = new ListNode<>(3, list);

        LList2<Integer> temp = new LList2<>(list, rear);

        temp.printWhile();

        temp.addLast(-2);

        temp.printWhile();
    }
}

class ListNode<E> {
    private final E val;
    private ListNode<E> next;

    public ListNode(E val, ListNode<E> next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public E getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public ListNode<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    public void updateNext(ListNode<E> node) {
        next = node;
    }
}


class LList2<E> {
    private ListNode<E> front;
    private ListNode<E> rear;

    public LList2(ListNode<E> front, ListNode<E> rear) {
        this.front = front;
        this.rear = rear;
    }

    public void printWhile() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (ListNode<E> temp = front; temp != null; temp = temp.getNext()) {
            sb.append(temp.getVal());
            if (temp.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }

        sb.append("]");
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    public void printFor() {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (ListNode<E> temp = front; temp != null; temp = temp.getNext()) {
            System.out.print(temp.getVal() + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }

    // obj represents value
    public void addFirst(E obj) {
        front = new ListNode<E>(obj, front);
        if (front.getNext() == null) {
            rear = front;
        }
    }

    public void addLast(E obj) {
        if (rear != null)
            rear.updateNext(new ListNode<E>(obj, null));
        else {
            rear = new ListNode<E>(obj, null);
            front = rear;

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forget that the parameter for addLast should not be a node